# Is there any option to display the values from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

i want to display the value in another sheet by a solution. so that when we enter a code it must search from the last sheet and generate value. pls check

Comment: Arya, I believe that you have asked this same question six different times recently.  Perhaps clarifying your question, and provdiing more details, if we are not helping you resolve your issue, might get you a better result.  Editing your question to remove details is not helpful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A10, QUERY(
 {'Please Solve'!$A$2:$B$10;'Please Solve'!$C$2:$D$10},
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col1 <>'' order by Col1,Col2 ", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]